# Bayesian approach to removing outliers from a normal distribution

Tags: bayesian, outliers

A lot of what I've seen for Bayesian approaches to removing outliers is for a linear model, not a normal distribution. Is there a way we can take a Bayesian approach to remove outliers from a normal distribution? I used Turing to get the means and standard deviations of a theoretical distribution and want to remove outliers by comparing our data set to the model generated by a MCMC. I have been told to avoid Z-scores because they are not Bayesian.

Comment: What exactly is your data? What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to remove outliers? Why not use a model that has longer tails than Gaussian, so the values are not outliers anymore?

Comment: @Tim I have western blot protein concentrations. We want to remove outliers so I can do group comparisons between a control group and 2 experimental groups.

Comment: That sounds a little fishy: removing outliers is a great way to achieve predetermined results.  This is why people are very, very careful about identifying and analyzing outliers.  Removing outliers is almost never needed to perform a rigorous comparison between two groups.